# selenium docker image selenium/node-chrome:3.11.0-dysprosium works on Chrome 66, but derived custom image with chrome 81 fails to start tests

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, grid

I am working on implementing selenium docker grid in my project. I am facing problem when connecting with a custom defined node-chrome docker node containers with updated browser version. Below are the details.

Environment:
Windows 10 base machine
Ubuntu 18.04/16.04 virtual machine.

Project:
Python Pytest Selenium

The test cases run fine when run with selenium/hub:3.11.0-dysprosium and selenium/node-chrome:3.11.0-dysprosium . The image was created with selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar and chrome version 66 and those are downloaded from https://hub.docker.com/

Then, creating a custom docker image  based on selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar and with latest chrome/chormedriver version i.e. 81.

**Steps to create docker image:**

Please refer  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Building-your-own-images

```
•   git clone https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium.git
•   cd docker-selenium
•   git checkout tags/3.11.0-dysprosium
•   make generate_all
•   sudo docker build -t selenium/node-chrome:1.2 --build-arg CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=81.0.4044.69 --build-arg CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-stable=81.0.4044.92-1 NodeChrome
```

Once the image is build, I am using this local image in the docker-compose file.

The hub and node are launched successfully, chrome session is also created, but the python+pytest test hangs.

```
[1586871890.350][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)  [Based on the googling, actually this error should not be a stopper to test run, but mentioning it here]

“13:44:50.256 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}) on port 17653
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1586871890.350][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
13:44:50.850 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: W3C
13:44:50.927 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session 98b823ca35a6d3cc17e666b7911551c4 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)”
```

The same test pass when run through standalone server node and hub (w/o docker) and test were running on chrome browser version 80+.
Please note, the project code is yet is not updated to work with higher version of on selenium-server-standalone.

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.11.0-dysprosium
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports: 
     - "4444:4444"
    environment:
      - GRID_DEBUG=true
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:1.2
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    ports: 
     - 9901:9500
     - 5555:5555
    expose: 
      - "9515"
      - "5555"
    environment:
      - GRID_DEBUG=true
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
      - NODE_BROWSER_NAME=chrome
      - NODE_SELENIUM_PROTOCOL=WebDriver
      - DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=2
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=2
      - VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    links:
      - selenium-hub
    privileged: true
```